# Unable to update managers name in Azure AD

Tags: azure

I followed through.

```
Set-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId "df19e8e6-2ad7-453e-87f5-037f6529ae16" -RefObjectId "df19e8e6-2ad7-453e-87f5-037f6529ae16".
```

No Luck. Through script also unable to do.

```
Get-AzureADUser : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.
At line:7 char:61
+ ... ger -ObjectId (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $row.'User Username').Object ...
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzureADUser], ParameterBindingValidationExcep 
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Open.Azure 
   AD16.PowerShell.GetUser.
```

Comment: Can you share more lines of the relevant script please? ‚ Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $row.'User Username'‘ looks a little strange as to why would a column (assuming you import from csv) called ‚User Username‘ have the ObjectId? If it doesn‘t, then the error message makes sense since it would not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that `$row.'User Username'` does not have a value.

As a test to confirm this you could add a line to your code to write the value to the console such as `Write-Host $row.'User Username'`

The value expected by the [Get-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) cmdlet is in fact the `ObjectId` so the line does not make much sense to me anyways. Why would you run a cmdlet to get the ObjectId when you already have it in `$row.'User Username'`.

You should either confirm that `$row.'User Username'` is not `$null` and contains the ObjectId or use one of the other alternatives outlined in the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0).

Comment: Example #2 in the linked article seems incorrect btw. It should certainly reference the ObjectId.